# Html 5 app Calling Azure server

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, wcf, azure

I have HTML 5 app that needs to communicate with Azure server (cross domain),
What is the best way to communicate between them?
I want to use jquery on the client side, and I wonder whether to use Jsonp (because of the cross domain)?

Server side:
1. generic handler (asax file) ?
2. wcf service (svc file) ? 
3. Ajax enable wcf service?

Any other idea will be welcome

Comment: Don't forget option 4. Create a bridging service on your server to pull down the request from the cross-domain server avoiding any cross-domain issues (as it all comes down from your server).

Comment: @HiTechMagic can you be more specefic? can you show me an example

Comment: Create a Web Api and publish to a Windows Azure Web Site or Windows Azure Cloud Services (web role). Then, you can enable Cors (there's a official nuget for that, just search for Cors).

Comment: What type of service are you accessing, REST? It will help if you provide more detail. If so, basically you write a REST service on your own server that simply pulls down the content from the other REST service and returns it from your server. This also protects you from changes on a third-party server (e.g. you can reformat the data if needed, or if it changes outside your control). You can even change providers transparently (i.e. without touching your client code).